# xamarin, parsing html to c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, xamarin

I'm doing the Xamarin project. There are an asp.net mvc and sql database. I've tried to convert html table to datatable or dataset. But its difficult for me. I tried HtmlAgility but it didnt work. How can I convert [this table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrY8l.png)  ??

`< h2>Index`

```
<a href="/DatabaseFirst/oyunlar/Create">Create New</a>
<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>
        oyun_adi
    </th>
    <th>
        oyun_tarihi
    </th>
    <th>
        oyun_aciklama
    </th>
    <th>
        oyun_suresi
    </th>
    <th>
        oyun_foto
    </th>
    <th>
        tur_adi
    </th>
    <th>
        salon_adi
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr></code>
```

Comment: With HtmlAgilityPack, what problem did you get? You can parse your html with HtmlAgilityPack and inspect each table node and create your own datatable with inspected table node's value. would like to see your effort so far so that we can give you right direction.

Comment: Do you have access to the server?  You should really create a webservice that will return the data as json instead of scraping the HTML.  But if you must go that route, consider using https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp

Comment: For example: I have code like this: "HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(text);"  but there're errors like 
"Error CS0103 The name 'LoadHtml' does not exist in the current context." 6+635

Comment: Yes I've. Okey I will try json

Answer (score 0):

Try YQL

https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/

It will allow you to select HTML data over the web saving on bandwidth.